# interaction term not in expected direction

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, interaction

I am  conducting a hierarchical regression analysis to test interaction effects.  The main variable and the moderator are related to the dependent variable significantly and in expected direction. 
Although the interaction term are significant they are in the unexpected direction. This problem exists for only one group and for the another group the interaction term is significant in the expected direction. 
Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this issue? Has it got to do with multicollinearity?

A second question 
How to interpret region of significance?